# Not 100% sure on Try /Catch

Tags: java

I have been asked to convert this code with a throw exception IF to a try/catch block. I have set it up but am not sure what to put in lieu of the word output so that it may run. I am not sure after reading the book and oracles info try/catch I see what needs to be done so the txt file will print. I will post code to be modified and then my change with try/catch. thanks for any help.

```
  public class WriteData {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   java.io.File file = new java.io.File("scores.txt");
    if (file.exists()) {
     System.out.println("File already exists");
     System.exit(0);
  }

  // Create a file
  java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);

  // Write formatted output to the file
  output.print("John T Smith ");
  output.println(90);
  output.print("Eric K Jones ");
  output.println(85);

  // Close the file
  output.close();
}
  }
```

Here is the code changed for the Try/Catch

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class WriteData {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   java.io.File file = new java.io.File("scores.txt");



try {
    output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
        }


    // Create a file
    java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);


    // Write formatted output to the file
    output.print("John T Smith ");
    output.println(90);
    output.print("Eric K Jones ");
    output.println(85);

   // Close the file
   output.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: So what's your problem? Can't print?

Comment: move the catch to the last line of your method

Comment: Just put everything in the try except the catch (containing the stack trace print).

Comment: I rearranged this @zgc7009 to have all of it in the try with catch at the end. Now I am getting an erro on output=new java.io.PrintWriter(file); the error is "output" cannot be resolved to a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
    output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file); // output is not defined yet
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
        }


// Create a file
// This one will throw the FileNotFoundException
java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);
```

You can modify it like this

```
try {
        java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file); 
        //rest of the code

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

- You are instanciating two times output when it is not needed.
- All treatment related to output should be done in the try block so it is not executed if an error happen and the stack is redirected to exception block.
- The output should be in a finally block to make sure the file is closed whatever happen.

Doing these correction, your code shoud look like this :

```
import java.io.*;

public class WriteData {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         File file = null;
         PrintWriter output = null;

        try
        {
            file = new File("scores.txt");
            output = new PrintWriter(file);

            output.print("John T Smith ");
            output.println(90);
            output.print("Eric K Jones ");
            output.println(85);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            //The output not be instanciated if scores.txt was not found.
            if(output != null)
                output.close();
        }
   }
}
```

In my opinion, this is the best way to handle your case.

Comment: Yes this works, except there is a compiler error with the IOException. I am also concerned that since this is changing it more then I was asked, it may be outside of what my instructor was trying to have us get.

Comment: What is the error ? I don't have access to a computer atm (I'm on iPad).. Also, I'm sure your teacher will be happy to see you've did more than what he asked (if you understand it for sure). If there is anything I can clarify please tell me.

Comment: The error is " unreachable catch block for IOException,only more specifc exceptions are thrown and they are handled by prevoius catch blocks." In CMD prompr it is unreachable catch clause

Comment: Fixed it. Note that since java 7, ressources can be automatically handled in try/catch... You should read some tutorial on this.

Answer (score 0):

For your error:

Remove the catch block for IoException from jean-François Savard's solution.

FileNotFoundException is a checked exception thrown by PrintWriter(). As a practice only catch the exceptions declared in API signature.

(In fact keeping any one block should work, as FileNotFoundException extends IOException )